# Made a erc-20 usdt transaction to myself by mistake

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

So i made this transfer, it was confirmed, but etherscan somehow shows that's it is "out" but never "in", and my balance is down for the sent amount. Anything i can do?

Comment: When need to see the transaction (add tx hash) and which balance is down? Ur ether balance or usdt balance?

Comment: My usdt balance is down for the amount of transfer and my eth balance is down for the amount of gas fee. And on the blockchain it looks like it left my address but never arrived to my address which does not make sense to me at all. Like, i had 1000 usdt, sent 1000 usdt to myself and now my balance is 0 usdt. So where did it go i wonder. I can't provide tx hash because it's a sizeable transaction.

Comment: @7588 Can you provide the transaction hash?

Comment: okay without the tx hash we sadly can’t explain it. the only answer that is possible ~> u made a mistake while writing ur address, or you or someone else spent those token in a previous tx and forgot about it. It is very common and I know people who did that :(